# How to fetch the events from local calendar in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, ekeventkit

```
func fetchEvent()
    {
    
        var store = EKEventStore()

        let calendars = store.calendars(for: .event)

        for calendar in calendars {

                let oneMonthAgo =  Date()
                let oneMonthAfter = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30*24*3600)
                let predicate =  store.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneMonthAgo, end: oneMonthAfter, calendars: [calendar])
                
                let events = store.events(matching: predicate)
                
                for event in events {
                    titles.append(event.title)
                    startDates.append(event.startDate)
                    endDates.append(event.endDate)
             }
    }
```

[I] use this code to fetch the stored events from the my local calendar. I stored many events in my local calendar but in events always it 0 element. So anyone please help me.

Comment: 1) Are you authorized to access the calendar? 2) The outer for loop is not necessary, the predicate takes an array of calendars 3) Never do `86400` date math, use the `Calendar` API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't forget to update your Info.plist with a NSCalendarsUsageDescription  by adding a new row:

- **Key:** "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description"
- **Value:** "Please give access" - this is up to you

Your ViewController should look similar to this:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    var titles: [String] = []
    var startDates: [Date] = []
    var endDates: [Date] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchEventsFromCalendar()
    }

    func fetchEventsFromCalendar() -> Void {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined: requestAccessToCalendar("Calendar")
        case .authorized: fetchEventsFromCalendar("Calendar")
        case .denied: print("Access denied")
        default: break
        }
    }

    func requestAccessToCalendar(_ calendarTitle: String) {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (_, _) in
            self.fetchEventsFromCalendar(calendarTitle)
        }
    }

    func fetchEventsFromCalendar(_ calendarTitle: String) -> Void {
        for calendar in eventStore.calendars(for: .event) {
            if calendar.title == calendarTitle {
                let oneMonthAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
                let oneMonthAfter = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
                let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(
                    withStart: oneMonthAgo,
                    end: oneMonthAfter,
                    calendars: [calendar]
                )
                let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
                for event in events {
                    titles.append(event.title)
                    startDates.append(event.startDate as Date)
                    endDates.append(event.endDate as Date)
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the event titles so check if everything works correctly
        print(titles)
    }

}
```

You'll first check from Calendar access in `fetchEventsFromCalendar()`, and the actual event fetching will be handled in `fetchEventsFromCalendar()`.

One thing: in this particular example we're looking for events one month before and one month after toady in a calendar called *"Calendar"*. If you want to get the events for that period of time from all the calendars, you can simply remove the

```
            if calendar.title == calendarTitle {
```

line (including the closing bracket and everything that has to do with `calendarTitle`). You'll have an array of all the events.